# How to to use if and else statements properly?

Tags: java, string, sorting, netbeans

I am having trouble using my `if` and `else if` statements for my personal project.

My program seems to work fine in the first lines when asking the user for input, but there is a problem in the code.  My compiler is asking me to use a switch method.

I've also encountered a problem where the compiler tells me I can't convert `String` to `double`, which is something I have already found using the search.

I know this might be a lot to ask but I would really appreciate your help.

```
/**
* This application executes number of gallons purchased, car wash if the 
* customer desires.  
* There will be four options, Regular, Premium, Super,
* or None.  A car wash is $1.25 if purchased with $10.00 or more.  If it is 
* anything equal or below $9.99 then the car wash fee is $3.00.  
* Regular per gallon is $2.89
* Premium per gallon is $3.09
* Super per gallon is $3.39
* 
* 
* @author Christian Guerra
*/
package finalflight;


//The line below is preparing the system to ask the user for inputs
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ExxonCarServices {

public static void main(String[] args) {


       String gasType;
       String carWash;
       String gasPrice;
       String numGallons;
       double gasRegular = 2.89;
       double gasPremium = 3.09;
       double gasSuper = 3.39;
       double gasNone = 0;

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Hello which type of gas would you like today?  "
               + "Please make the selection Regular, Premium, Super, or None" + " ");

       gasType = keyboard.nextLine();

       System.out.print("How many gallons would you like?" + " ");

       numGallons = keyboard.nextLine();

       System.out.print("Would you like to add a professional car wash cleaning today?"  
       + " " + "Please select Yes or No" + " ");

       carWash = keyboard.nextLine();



     if (gasType.equals("Regular")) { 

        gasRegular = Regular;

     } else if (gasType.equals ("Premium")) {

        gasPremium = Premium;
     } else if (gasType.equals("Super")) {

        gasSuper = Super;

     } else { 

        gasNone = 0;
 }



    if (numGallons * gasPrice <10) {

        carWash = 3;

    } else {

        carWash = 1.25;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [clear and concise, minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the problem you're having. Further, please post the **exact** error you're receiving. I've never heard of a compiler telling you which constructs to use.

Comment: Your use of if... then... else is fine. The problem is that you have gasRegular defined as a double, but then you attempt to set gasRegular = Regular, which I'm assuming is some String constant (you haven't included the part of your code where you define "Regular", "Premium" and "Super" unless I somehow missed it. Show us the code where those values are set.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that this code is correct:

```
if (gasType.equals("Regular")) { 
  gasRegular = Regular;
} ...
```

but starting with Java 7.0 can also be written using a switch statement:

```
switch (gasType) {
case "Regular":
  gasRegular = Regular;
  break;
case "Premium":
  gasPremium = Premium;
  break;
  ....
}
```

The error you're getting about "can't convert String to double" is probably due to a missing `Double.parseDouble(someString)` when assigning a `String` to a variable of the type `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the compiler is *telling* you to use a switch-case, it's probably just suggesting it (for more than a few items, a switch-case is almost always the better option for readability's sake).

To convert a `String` to a `Double`, simply use `Double.parseDouble()`.

In your case, that would look something like this:

```
double numGallonsDouble = Double.parseInt(numGallons);
```